# HTL code to fetch list from sling model to HTML page

Tags: aem, sightly

I have created Sling model which is fetching the root page and its child pages. I added the title and description of all the pages in List.

My bean class is as follows

```
Items(String title, String description, List<Items>)
```

I have list of this `Items` bean class in my sling model and added the content in this list.
`List<Items>` in parameter is for the child pages to be stored in it.

How can I fetch this list values in my HTL code to display it on page using sightly?
What will be the code for this?

Answer (score 1):

You would normally expose the list of times with a getter method:

```
public List<Items> getItems() { ... }
```

Assuming each items also exposes getters for `title` and `description`:

```
public String getTitle() { ... }
public String getDescription() { ... }
```

Then you can just use your model:

```
<ul data-sly-use.myModel="MyModelClass" data-sly-list="myModel.items">
    <li>${item.title} - ${item.description}</li>
</ul>
```

There are some more examples in the [HTL specification](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#226-list).

Comment: Yes I have included getters and setters for all the fields. Also in used my model in HTL using `data-sly-use` and I tried this way but its not working. Title and description of pages are not displayed.

Comment: You would need to provide more detailed information

Comment: As @Vlad said, you need to provide more information for anybody to be able to help.  Presumably, your `Items` model is adaptable from page, you inject the title `@Named("jcr:title")` and description properties, as well as the child pages, which are adapted to `Items`.  Is that correct?  Or are you manually constructing the `List<Items>`?  Let's get more basic...  when you `data-sly-use` your model, can you access the title and description properties of that model itself (rather than trying to access those properties for the children)?  Have you tried debugging your model to check the data?